# Does torture work well as an interrogation technique?

Tags: history, psychology, politics, law

Wikipedia's [Effectiveness of torture for interrogation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effectiveness_of_torture_for_interrogation) says,

> Torture has been used throughout history for the purpose of obtaining information in interrogation. **Some arguments say that it is an effective way of making someone divulge vital information whilst others say it is [violent, horrific and] useless.**

It links to a New York Times article, [Interrogations’ Effectiveness May Prove Elusive](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/04/23/us/politics/23detain.html?_r=0), which includes opinions from both sides of the debate.

So, completely disregarding moral aspects and other consequences, **is torture useful in interrogation**?  Is it feasible to torture accurate information out of people?  Is it feasible to determine whether the information is likely accurate without outside confirmation?

Also related would be whether other interrogation techniques are better at extracting accurate information and confirming its accuracy.

Comment: @WernerSchmitt: While I'm strongly anti-torture, I'm also strongly anti-censorship.  How can one argue against torture if your not willing to take a hard look at whether it works?  Pro-torture advocates would dismiss one's position as naive for not addressing their arguments.

Comment: Werner, some people will argue that torture is unethical whether it is effective or not. Some people will argue that the ends justify the means. If it can be shown that torture is ineffective, these two moral positions align. So, to me it seems to be a perfectly reasonable question to be addressed.

Comment: @mark Well, obviously it works :( IMO The argument vs. torture is NOT that people might lie due to specific torture techniques. But torturing is violating human rights. Again as stated in META i have MY problems with questions on human behaviour and explaining & generalizing it. Thats not how psychology works, but psychiatry, torturing humans with medicaments. What answers are you expecting here, torture-studies!? Hopefully not...Question is quite rhetorical and more likely ending in legitimating than objectively analyzing torture...

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that most people ask this question operating under the assumption that the person being interrogated actually knows something, which is often not the case.  If they don't know anything or know very little, they will just make stuff up in order to make the torture stop because they know it will continue if they tell the truth, which is that they know nothing.  Even if it were the case that torture was more effective against people who actually knew something, any benefits would offset by false information gotten from those who just made things up.

Comment: @Werner:  I asked the question for the exact reasons Oddthinking suggested.  I can argue my ethical positions, which appear to be much the same as yours, but I really wanted material to counter "the end justifies the means".  The easiest potential way to refute that is to know, and be able to establish, that the ends aren't all that impressive.

Comment: Something that hasn't been addressed at all here is what *kind* of information people would have that someone would want to interrogate to get, and the motives that interrogatees would have for wishing to keep this hidden under torture. That is, the *ideology* of the person being tortured seems important. Let's focus less on the mechanics. When a person keeps information undisclosed under torture due to deeply-held ideological beliefs (religion, country, group loyalty, etc.), of *course* mere force will not work. An alteration of the person's ideological framework is necessary.

Comment: For example, as your prisoner of war, if you wanted to know what I had for breakfast I would probably tell you. But if you wanted to know where my command center was, I would resist because this is information that would harm my comrades, to whom I have loyalty (and I have resistance to you). If instead I was subtly manipulated in a way that reduced my hostility to you and lessened my identification with my compatriots, I would be more willing to release the information because, like the contents of my breakfast, I'd have less reason to keep it secret.

Comment: One of the problems with this question is it lacks any context. First, what is and is not "Torture". If one uses the "UN" definition then damn near anything can be called "torture". Second, What constitutes "Interrogation" (or an "interrogation technique")? Most people have watch too much 24 (or other media distortions of _interrogations_) to actually understand how **REAL** interrogation works. It is **NOT** possible for a person being interrogated to "_Just say whatever in order to make it stop._", there too many control questions for that. Finally, what is the standard for "**Work Well**"?

Comment: @Werner "obviously it works" [citation-needed] This isn't a "Skeptics" for nothing...

Comment: The police use it all the time with great success. Everybody knows that. Bullies at school use it quite effectively too.

Comment: @Captain Claptrap "Everybody knows that." I don't. Have you any evidence? Bullies don't use torture to extract useful information; they use it (well, a childish form of it) to extract money and for personal gratification, neither of which are relevant.

Comment: @Werner, I'll hope you'll agree that, in hindsight, your fears about the answers to this question haven't been realised.

Comment: @oddthinking well this is the myth building i mentioned in META. The political correct answer was voted mostly, i was not afraid of this, i expected this, and my comment and the following pushed the drama of this question pretty much in this direction. But is the answer objective (what skeptics.SE **should be about**)? If the to get tortured guy knows, that the torturer knows, that he has the info the torturer is seeking for, torture will work well. But obviously one cant cite a study proofing this, thats why i was against this question, the doubting comments DVK beneath remain legitimating

Comment: @Mark @Oddthinking - I'm anti-censorship too. IMO the question of whether it's effective is orthogonal to the question of whether it's moral. No matter whether it's effective, you resist torturing people because you (you individually and as a society) are better than that. It's the same kind of argument that you use for race: yes there are slight differences between races, and no we don't use that to discriminate against individuals. Speaking as a vegetarian, the facts of whether animals are tasty or nutritious are permissible, but irrelevant/orthogonal to whether it's appropriate to eat them.

Comment: I'd suggest to take the discussion whether we should allow this quesiton either to meta or to chat, it's a bit too much for the comments here.

Comment: Torture works so well CIA use it. Otherwise why would they?

Comment: This is a great article giving examples of the effectiveness of torture: http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~jim/torturecardozo.pdf

Comment: @JimThio, "The CIA's justification for the use of its enhanced interrogation techniques rested on inaccurate claims of their effectiveness" according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senate_Intelligence_Committee_report_on_CIA_torture

Comment: I really doubt you will find quantitative measurable data on this, and all the "experts" will have huge politica\employment biases. The only point against it, that is taken too generally, is that it is easy to get confessions out of Innocent people, but that in fact happens all the time with normal interigations as well. But it at least has some ability of obtaining outside verifiable information. Ex, give me the combination to this safe and I will stop cutting you. And no matter how good non physical interrogation is, there are always sums number of suspects who never give in, to that.

Comment: What is the claim of which you are skeptical? The quoted text makes no claim one way or the other - all it says is that some people think it works well, other people don't think it works well.

Comment: All the answers and quotes up to now have a very mild notion of torture, like just a bit of pain and go home. In reality, the subject's dead afterwards. There's no use for the operator to stop at any time, he's never "satisfied" with answers, it ends only because he lacks skill in keeping the subject's vital body functions working.

Answer (score 757, accepted):

**Short answer**: Your friends who think torture is effective at getting *reliable* information are ***wrong***.

**New Edit/info**:  Since this is in the news (December 2014), the [Senate Select Committee on Intelligence has just recently issued a report (PDF)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150524072101/http://www.intelligence.senate.gov/study2014/sscistudy1.pdf) on torture activities that the US engaged in (the link is the 500 page version). While the majority of details concern specific activities and practices, there are several conclusions that came from this report.  One of the chief findings regarding the effectiveness of torture was that it wasn't, and any instances of it being reported as having played a role were fabrications by the CIA to justify their continued program (findings and conclusions items #1 and #2 as well as #10 stating the dissemination of inaccurate information). Finding and conclusion #8 would even indicate that these actions complicated and impeded US security.

[Army Field Manual 34-52 Chapter 1 says](https://www.globalsecurity.org/intell/library/policy/army/fm/fm34-52/chapter1.htm):

> “Experience indicates that the use of force is not necessary to gain the cooperation of sources for interrogation. Therefore, the use of force is a poor technique, as it yields unreliable results, may damage subsequent collection efforts, and can induce the source to say whatever he thinks the interrogator wants to hear.”

[The C.I.A.’s 1963 interrogation manual stated](https://www.vanityfair.com/magazine/2008/12/torture200812?currentPage=2):

> Intense pain is quite likely to produce false confessions, concocted as a means of escaping from distress. A time-consuming delay results, while investigation is conducted and the admissions are proven untrue. During this respite the interrogatee can pull himself together. He may even use the time to think up new, more complex ‘admissions’ that take still longer to disprove.

[The act of torturing can even interfere with a subject's *ability* to tell the truth](https://www.newsweek.com/neurosciencetorture-doesnt-work-and-heres-why-79365).

> Solid scientific evidence on how repeated and extreme stress and pain affect memory and executive functions (such as planning or forming intentions) suggests these techniques are unlikely to do anything other than the opposite of that intended by coercive or 'enhanced' interrogation.

This Newsweek article also links to the [Trinity College Institute of Neuroscience](https://web.archive.org/web/20110721131955/http://neuroscience.tcd.ie/) in Dublin that has a paper in the journal [*Trends in Cognitive Science*](https://www.cell.com/trends/cognitive-sciences).  [It will cost you nearly $40 for the paper itself though](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1364661309001995).

In specifically dealing with the post 9/11 world, a work entitled [A utilitarian argument against torture interrogation of terrorists](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11948-004-0011-y) states in its abstract:

> Drawing from criminology, organizational theory, social psychology, the historical record, and my interviews with military professionals, I assess the potential of an official U.S. program of torture interrogation from a practical perspective. The central element of program design is a sound causal model relating input to output. I explore three principal models of how torture interrogation leads to truth: the animal instinct model, the cognitive failure model, and the data processing model. These models show why torture interrogation fails overall as a counterterrorist tactic.

Anyone remember the [Star Trek episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_Command_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) that dealt with this issue?  And this was before Waterboarding was part of our lexicon.

Furthermore, the [Society for the Psychological Study of Social Issues](https://www.spssi.org/index.cfm?fuseaction=page.viewpage&pageid=1460) states:

> ...there is no evidence that torture is an effective means of gathering reliable information.  Many survivors of torture report they that would have said anything to “make the torture stop” (Mayer, 2005; McCoy, 2005).  Those who make the claim that “torture works” offer as evidence only unverifiable anecdotal accounts.

[LiveScience sums it up very well in the title of an article from October 2007](https://www.livescience.com/4651-torture-long-history-working.html):

> Torture Has a Long History ... of Not Working

I went through the USAF SERE School, and I can tell you that even though we weren't "tortured" we were placed under numerous stressors, and we would do as many deceitful things to get out of those situations as possible (i.e. tell them what they wanted as opposed to the truth).  And we were even taught how to evade the torture by supplying plausible lies, and then "recover" from anything that may have been detrimental to our position as a POW.

**EDIT TO ADD**:  Someone asked if there are any methods for getting information quickly, and reliably.  The answer is, "It depends."  There are many, many techniques out there (Good Cop-Bad Cop, surprise, sympathy, etc.).  All of those really depend on the state of mind of the subject.  One really needs to get to know the subject before you can start to whittle away at them and find what you want/need.  And even then, it is wildly variable and depends a great deal on psychology.  The link to the [Army Field Manual 34-52](https://www.globalsecurity.org/intell/library/policy/army/fm/fm34-52/chapter1.htm) mentions some specialized training required:

> The interrogator requires specialized training in international regulations, security, and neurolinguistics.
>
> Neurolinguistics is a behavioral communications model and a set of procedures that improve communication skills. The interrogator should read and react to nonverbal communications. An interrogator can best adapt himself to the source's personality and control his own reactions when he has an understanding of basic psychological factors, traits, attitudes, drives, motivations, and inhibitions.

Also, keep in mind that HUMINT can be gathered much more reliably via other methods than direct interrogation.  The recent example of the courier that led to the raid on Osama bin Laden was all HUMINT gathered via tailing and observation.  DuckMaestro is interested in data, and every source I find says that interrogation isn't even a science, but rather an art...  How is one supposed to get data on that?  [A scholarly paper on Police Interrogation techniques, even highlights the art nature more than anything](https://scholarworks.utep.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1036&context=christian_meissner&sei-redir=1#search=%22comparison%20of%20interrogation%20techniques%20effectiveness%22) (PDF File).  The most effective that has some backing by studies seems to be the [Reid Technique of investigative interviewing](https://reid.com/), which seems to be a recap from the Army Field Manual.  Also, some folks may be interested in reading about [Hanns Scharff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanns_Scharff), considered one of the most successful interrogators of WW II.

> He has been highly praised for the success of his techniques, in particular because he never used physical means to obtain the required information

**WHY USE IT?**  So why do people use it, or promote it?  While probably beyond the scope of the answer, I wanted to address this with a couple of thoughts.  First of all, human beings are animals.  There is a visceral need to hurt your enemy.  If you have captured an enemy, it may seem callous to hurt him for the sake of hurting him, so "enhanced interrogation" is a nice *rationalization*.  [And as long as you are told to do so by an authority figure, many people will comply](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/7791278.stm) (as also highlighted by the original [Milgram Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment)).  Also, many of the proponents for torture have a vested interest in ensuring that it isn't deemed illegal.  They would face prosecution should their actions be deemed illegal!  That is self-preservation.

***I will add, torture IS effective at intimidation***, and keeping people "in line" under an authoritative regime.  In that respect, there is a great deal of historical evidence (recent history like Saddam, Pinochet, Iran; or older history like the Inquisitions or Roman methods).  In that sense, it is a very effective tool, but generally not for the stated purpose of getting reliable information.  But it will get a lot of false confessions that can be used for propaganda and other purposes.  Not only that, *some* people will indeed give information ([as cited in this article](https://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2004/12/tort-d13.html)), however the overwhelming evidence is again that it may not be reliable, and what have you sacrificed in order to obtain that information?

---

**INFORMATION BEYOND JUST INITIAL REFUTATION**: I just found a HUGE list of quotes as well.  Let me go through them and get a few more for you.  This is a long list of policy quotes, and people involved in the intelligence fields, so it really won't have a lot of actual research citations to back it up, since researching torture is highly unethical.  Although, I think the [Stanford Study](https://news.stanford.edu/pr/97/970108prisonexp.html) may be about as close as you can get.  My apologies for some of the references, they aren't always the most impartial, or reliable, so anything below this should probably be taken with a grain of salt.  And of course, should you want to read it all, the inescapable conclusion is that torture does not work as a reliable interrogation technique, and never has.

According to the Washington Post, the CIA’s top spy – [Michael Sulick, head of the CIA’s National Clandestine Service – said](https://web.archive.org/web/20141111220857/http://blog.washingtonpost.com/spy-talk/2010/04/cias_top_spy_no_losses_from_wa.html) that the spy agency has seen no fall-off in intelligence since waterboarding was banned by the Obama administration. “I don’t think we’ve suffered at all from an intelligence standpoint.”

The [CIA’s own Inspector General wrote](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/ig-report-waterboarding-w_n_201733) that waterboarding was not “efficacious” in producing information.

A 30-year veteran of CIA’s operations directorate who rose to the most senior managerial ranks (Milton Bearden) [says (as quoted by senior CIA agent and Presidential briefer Ray McGovern)](https://www.consortiumnews.com/2009/020609a.html):

> It is irresponsible for any administration not to tell a credible story that would convince critics at home and abroad that this torture has served some useful purpose.  This is not just because the old hands overwhelmingly believe that torture doesn’t work — it doesn’t — but also because they know that torture creates more terrorists and fosters more acts of terror than it could possibly neutralize.

A former high-level CIA officer (Philip Giraldi) [states](https://web.archive.org/web/20120405133741/http://www.campaignforliberty.com:80/article.php?view=94):

> Many governments that have routinely tortured to obtain information have abandoned the practice when they discovered that other approaches actually worked better for extracting information. Israel prohibited torturing Palestinian terrorist suspects in 1999. Even the German Gestapo stopped torturing French resistance captives when it determined that treating prisoners well actually produced more and better intelligence.

A retired C.I.A. officer who oversaw the interrogation of a high-level detainee in 2002 [(Glenn L. Carle) says](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/04/us/politics/04torture.html?_r=3):

> [Coercive techniques] didn’t provide useful, meaningful, trustworthy information…Everyone was deeply concerned and most felt it was un-American and did not work.”

A former top Air Force interrogator who led the team that tracked down Abu Musab al-Zarqawi, who has conducted hundreds of interrogations of high ranking Al Qaida members and supervising more than one thousand, and wrote a book called *How to Break a Terrorist* [writes](https://web.archive.org/web/20110515064449/http://www.thedailybeast.com/blogs-and-stories/2009-04-20/torture-doesnt-work/#):

> As the senior interrogator in Iraq for a task force charged with hunting down Abu Musab Al Zarqawi, the former Al Qaida leader and mass murderer, I listened time and time again to captured foreign fighters cite the torture and abuse at Abu Ghraib and Guantanamo as their main reason for coming to Iraq to fight. Consider that 90 percent of the suicide bombers in Iraq are these foreign fighters and you can easily conclude that we have lost hundreds, if not thousands, of American lives because of our policy of torture and abuse. But that’s only the past.
>
> Somewhere in the world there are other young Muslims who have joined Al Qaida because we tortured and abused prisoners. These men will certainly carry out future attacks against Americans, either in Iraq, Afghanistan, or possibly even here. And that’s not to mention numerous other Muslims who support Al Qaida, either financially or in other ways, because they are outraged that the United States tortured and abused Muslim prisoners.
>
> In addition, torture and abuse has made us less safe because detainees are less likely to cooperate during interrogations if they don’t trust us. I know from having conducted hundreds of interrogations of high ranking Al Qaida members and supervising more than one thousand, that when a captured Al Qaida member sees us live up to our stated principles they are more willing to negotiate and cooperate with us. When we torture or abuse them, it hardens their resolve and reaffirms why they picked up arms.

[He also says](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109015040/https://www.rawstory.com/news/2008/Former_interrogator_speaks_out_against_torture_1204.html):

> [Torture is] extremely ineffective, and it’s counter-productive to what we’re trying to accomplish.
>
> When we torture somebody, it hardens their resolve … The information that you get is unreliable. … And even if you do get reliable information, you’re able to stop a terrorist attack, al Qaeda’s then going to use the fact that we torture people to recruit new members.

[And he repeats](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2008/11/28/AR2008112802242.html):

> I learned in Iraq that the No. 1 reason foreign fighters flocked there to fight were the abuses carried out at Abu Ghraib and Guantanamo.

[He said last month](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/torture-may-have-slowed-h_n_858642):

> They don’t want to talk about the long term consequences that cost the lives of Americans…. [The way the U.S. treated its prisoners] was al-Qaeda’s number-one recruiting tool and brought in thousands of foreign fighters who killed American soldiers.

The [FBI interrogators who actually interviewed some of the 9/11](https://talkingpointsmemo.com/muckraker/img-src-http-talkingpointsmemo-com-images-zubaydah-muck-jpg-vspace-5-hspace-5-align-left-today-s-must-read) suspects say torture didn’t work.

[Another FBI interrogator of 9/11 suspects said](https://www.newsweek.com/ali-soufan-breaks-his-silence-77243):

> I was in the middle of this, and it’s not true that these [aggressive] techniques were effective.

[A third former FBI interrogator — who interrogated Al Qaeda suspects — says categorically that torture does not help collect intelligence](https://boingboing.net/2008/03/10/fbi-interrogator-tor.html). On the other hand he says that torture actually turns people into terrorists.

[The FBI warned military interrogators in 2003 that enhanced interrogation techniques are “of questionable effectiveness”](https://web.archive.org/web/20111017002530/http://action.aclu.org/torturefoia/released/022306/1261.pdf) and cited a “lack of evidence of [enhanced techniques’] success.

“When long-time FBI director Mueller was asked whether any attacks on America been disrupted thanks to intelligence obtained through “enhanced techniques”, he responded [“I don’t believe that has been the case.”](https://www.vanityfair.com/magazine/2008/12/torture200812?currentPage=4)

The Senate Armed Services Committee unanimously [found](https://harpers.org/archive/2008/12/hbc-90004012) that torture doesn’t work, [stating](https://web.archive.org/web/20190930211243/https://washingtonsblog.com/2008/12/its-official-torture-doesnt-work.html):

> The administration’s policies concerning [torture] and the resulting controversies damaged our ability to collect accurate intelligence that could save lives, strengthened the hand of our enemies, and compromised our moral authority.

The military agency which actually provided advice on harsh interrogation techniques for use against terrorism suspects warned the Pentagon in 2002 that those techniques would produce “[unreliable information](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/04/24/AR2009042403171_pf.html).”

[General Petraeus says](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126145400/https://www.washingtonsblog.com/2010/02/general-patraeus-torture-is.html) that torture is unnecessary, hurts our national security and violates our American values.

Retired 4-star General Barry McCaffrey – who Schwarzkopf called the hero of Desert Storm – [agrees](https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2009/04/22/723297/-4-Star-General-Calls-for-Probe-of-Bush-White-House).

The number 2 terrorism expert for the State Department [says torture doesn’t work](https://web.archive.org/web/20090429095902/http://www.washingtonsblog.com:80/2009/02/high-level-counter-terrorism-official.html), and just creates more terrorists.

Former Navy Judge Advocate General [Admiral John Hutson says:](https://www.chron.com/news/nation-world/article/Retired-officers-urge-Obama-to-end-harsh-1775419.php)

> Fundamentally, those kinds of techniques are ineffective. If the goal is to gain actionable intelligence, and it is, and if that’s important, and it is, then we have to use the techniques that are most effective. Torture is the technique of choice of the lazy, stupid and pseudo-tough.

[Army Colonel Stuart Herrington](https://www.csmonitor.com/USA/Military/2011/0505/Military-interrogators-Waterboarding-didn-t-yield-tips-that-led-to-bin-Laden) – a military intelligence specialist who interrogated generals under the command of Saddam Hussein and evaluated US detention operations at Guantánamo – notes that the process of obtaining information is hampered, not helped, by practices such as “slapping someone in the face and stripping them naked”.

Herrington and other former US military interrogators say:

> We know from experience that it is very difficult to elicit information from a detainee who has been abused. The abuse often only strengthens their resolve and makes it that much harder for an interrogator to find a way to elicit useful information.

[Major General Thomas Romig, former Army JAG, said](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313063155/http://www2.gwu.edu:80/%7Ensarchiv/torturingdemocracy/interviews/thomas_romig.html):

> If you torture somebody, they’ll tell you anything. I don’t know anybody that is good at interrogation, has done it a lot, that will say that that’s an effective means of getting information. … So I don’t think it’s effective.

Brigadier General David R. Irvine, retired [Army Reserve strategic intelligence officer who taught prisoner interrogation and military law for 18 years](https://web.archive.org/web/20120520142905/http://www.alternet.org/rights/28585/) with the Sixth Army Intelligence School, says torture doesn’t work.

[The head of all U.S. intelligence said](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/04/21/AR2009042104334.html):

> The bottom line is these techniques have hurt our image around the world … The damage they have done to our interests far outweighed whatever benefit they gave us and they are not essential to our national security.

Former counter-terrorism czar [Richard A. Clarke says](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/05/29/AR2009052901560.html) that America’s indefinite detention without trial and abuse of prisoners is a leading Al Qaeda recruiting tool.

A [former U.S. interrogator and counterintelligence agent](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/moveon-pushes-back-on-git_n_209047), and Afghanistan veteran said,

> Torture puts our troops in danger, torture makes our troops less safe, torture creates terrorists. It’s used so widely as a propaganda tool now in Afghanistan. All too often, detainees have pamphlets on them, depicting what happened at Guantanamo.

The first head of the Department of Homeland Security – Tom Ridge – [says](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/americas/7903516.stm) we were wrong to torture.

The former British intelligence chairman [says](https://web.archive.org/web/20140806095843/http://www.rawstory.com:80/rs/2010/11/09/british-minister-calls-bush-liar-waterboarding-stop-terror-plots/) that waterboarding didn’t stop terror plots.

A spokesman for the National Security Council ([Tommy Vietor) says](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/04/us/politics/04torture.html?_r=2):

> The bottom line is this: If we had some kind of smoking-gun intelligence from waterboarding in 2003, we would have taken out Osama bin Laden in 2003.

The [Marines weren’t keen on torture](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/fbi-werent-the-only-ones_b_190708), either.

As [Vanity Fair reports](https://www.vanityfair.com/magazine/2008/12/torture200812):

> In researching this article, I spoke to numerous counterterrorist officials from agencies on both sides of the Atlantic. Their conclusion is unanimous: not only have coercive methods failed to generate significant and actionable intelligence, they have also caused the squandering of resources on a massive scale through false leads, chimerical plots, and unnecessary safety alerts…Here, they say, far from exposing a deadly plot, all torture did was lead to more torture of his supposed accomplices while also providing some misleading “information” that boosted the administration’s argument for invading Iraq.

An Army psychologist – Major Paul Burney, [Army’s Behavior Science Consulting Team psychologist – said (page 78 & 83)](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/documents/report-by-the-senate-armed-services-committee-on-detainee-treatment):

> It was stressed to me time and time again that psychological investigations have proven that harsh interrogations do not work. At best it will get you information that a prisoner thinks you want to hear to make the interrogation stop, but that information is strongly likely to be false.
>
> Interrogation techniques that rely on physical or adverse consequences are likely to garner inaccurate information and create an increased level of resistance…There is no evidence that the level of fear or discomfort evoked by a given technique has any consistent correlation to the volume or quality of information obtained.

An expert on resisting torture – Terrence Russell, JPRA’s manager for research and development and a SERE specialist – said ([page 209](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/documents/report-by-the-senate-armed-services-committee-on-detainee-treatment)):

> History has shown us that physical pressures are not effective for compelling an individual to give information or to do something’ and are not effective for gaining accurate, actionable intelligence.

Okay, I think that's enough for this answer.  I'll try to come back to this from time to time to add references and answers to questions.  Keep in mind this is a charged subject, but the main science says it isn't reliable.  And even if it were reliable, the ethics would cloud the issue beyond this site's charter, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I got a little passionate on that answer.  As someone who spent his adult life defending the Constitution, I have always felt that as a nation we were better than that, so employing torture is beyond morally wrong, but a detriment to our standing as a free nation.  Although, sadly I have found my voice as a minority in many circles I used to be part of.

Comment: It's worth noting that many of your sources that claim that torture doesn't work (such as the CIA) actually employ torture.. I wonder why. Maybe because it can be fun to finally make your enemy suffer, so the goal goes from obtaining information to revenge

Comment: @Andreas Bonini I think that it's because policy  decisions are driven at different levels.  The people who actually know about torture say it doesn't work (and publish such info), but then ideologues mandate such actions despite being told it doesn't work (like Bush/Cheney).  I think it has quite a bit to do with the "Conservative" mindset, but that's another discussion.

Comment: It's worth noting that the question states that *some* friends say it does work, while *others* say it doesn't. So when you say "Your friends are wrong"...

Comment: @Larian, I agree with the basic premise and clearly the evidence is overwhelming. Also I'd like to clarify that I find any form of torture despicable, but I would like to know, if there is any mean of "extracting" information of someone in a very short period of time, let's say one hour to one day. I wonder whether in that particular scenario, physical pain or it the threat of pain might be an effective mean, not justifiable on that we agree.

Comment: I don't have time to read through all the sources, but is there anything more you can quote in the answer to address torture vs. non-torture in comparitive and quantitative terms? I'd like to get an idea of whether non-torture techniques actually fair better, or whether there isn't a clear winner and that extracting information from a prisoner is equally challenging in any approach used. If you can include any comparative statistics on % likelihood of accurate information gathering between torture and non-torture, or related statistics/numbers, that'd be awesome.

Comment: @DuckMaestro, as I mentioned in my answer, just performing that sort of study is highly unethical!  However, if there were clear cases where torture had led to some critical piece of information, wouldn't the proponents be advertising that?  The lack of any such crowning achievement should be at least an indicator!

Comment: Certainly to perform that kind of study for the sake of a study is unethical, but I assume for all the techniques and interogations of the past, including any torturous, that there would be statistics kept on how effective each incident of interrogation was -- like internal review. If no-one is keeping numbers and counting the succesful and unsucessful outcomes of each technique then how do the government bodies actually know which techniques to promote the use of in the future? (ethics and political forces aside).

Comment: @DuckMaestro I think all the articles and information posted in my answer IS the documentation that says torture doesn't work.  The comparison are the numerous other techniques (mostly listed in that Army Field Manual), as the body of intelligence work.  Given that it is intelligence work, access to it will by its very nature be rather restricted.  And as I said earlier, if someone is convinced that they are right, no amount of data will change their minds if they have a specific mindset...

Comment: I'll focus my readings in the Army Field Manual first, thanks. Really though, my point is a suggestion for improving the answer by citing numbers (if any) instead of only quotes, even if the linked articles do have numbers already. Because A) you have a long and detailed answer with many links, and not many people will read through every link; and B) many people like to see empirical data/stats (when possible) to back up any cited quotes. I'm a math guy and numbers convince me the most. :) Though I understand that, as you said, not everything is made available to the public. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Larian - while this answer contains some useful information that pertains to the question, it suffers from two major problems: (1) Most of the quotes have an extremely large political angle where people saying those things have 100% clear and obvious reason to speak against torture **independently** of whether what they way is true or not

Comment: @Larian - (2) The REAL question is whether there are situation where torture yields results better than lack of it. ALL - 100% - of the reasons listed as "why torture doesn't work" - which pretty much amounts to "interrogated person will lie" - apply 100% equally as well to torture-less interrogation. Except more so - you have less pressure and therefore more likelyhood to come up with coherent lies with no stress.

Comment: @Larian - also, the point of Army Field Manual etc... is to dissuade people from using torture. Would YOU want to put in a training manual "well if you know what you're doing torture is useful" and hope to create people representing USA? See your first +8 comment. You - as a commander - REALLY don't want to be endorsing torture, especially in policy form - REGARDLESS of whether it works; for moral/ethical/political/optics reasons.

Comment: @DVK, @Larian -- aye, that is why I'd hope to see comparative numbers.

Comment: @Larian - I would feel significanly more convinced if ANY of your sources were people who would have no political/moral/ethical angle; since the question wasn't "is torture eithical".

Comment: You also might want to note that the vast majority of politicians that came out trying to defend the use of torture has *very* good reasons to want to make sure they don't get prosecuted for having ordered or signed off on torture...

Comment: @WOPR, because human beings are animals, and we will _rationalize_ the use of something to hurt our enemies and say that we have to.

Comment: Thinking about this further, @Shadur and @DVK make very good points. Because of the politics and conflicts of interest on both sides, I really don't see there being good answer to original question unless it highlights extensive data (including comparative data), or in lieu of data a framing along the lines of "we don't know for certain, however the following prominent individuals claim [...]". Unfortunately through this discussion I'm reminded of how much politics in particular have the potential to distort otherwise prima facie "expert" analysis.

Comment: @DuckMaestro, see the link I did add:  http://www.springerlink.com/content/h4q565424126068h/ Which says, `I explore three principal models of how torture interrogation leads to truth: the animal instinct model, the cognitive failure model, and the data processing model. These models show why torture interrogation fails overall as a counterterrorist tactic.` in the abstract.  May provide some harder data.

Comment: @glowcoder from what I have been taught and read, those who are not tortured will behave in the same myriad of ways people will behave under any stressful situation (i.e. unpredictably unless already well known and observed).  And a key aspect of SERE training is that it's the torturer doing the bad deed, no matter how they may tell you it's your fault for your friend being tortured, you know that it isn't, because you aren't the one actually doing it.  Again, the bottom line, it's not reliable, and other techniques have shown to bee (i.e. Reid).

Comment: @werner, that just shifts the problem - *how* do you know, with 100% certainty, that your victim actually does have the answer you need? And more importantly, how will you be sure that the answer he *gives you* is the actual truth? Blatantly unlikely scenarios like the plot of every 24 series aside -- come to think of it, even *in* that scenario. If I were a mortal enemy of the US and I knew of a bomb about to go off, I'd be able to concentrate on holding out against torture long enough for said bomb to go off, or giving bullshit info after a certain amount just to cost them enough time.

Comment: @Shadur, See this reference that I put in my answer:  http://www.newsweek.com/2009/09/21/the-tortured-brain.html  A torture victim's ABILITY to tell the truth is affected.

Comment: @Larian you should structure your post than a bit more IMHO, "under condition", "headings" it begins with **wrong** (followed by dozens of link i doubt anybody will read) which is too generalizing to me to offer a objective vote @Shadur the whole point of a torture is to **complete your knowledge**, to increase overall plausiblity, torture is than necessary but not sufficient to yield overall more truth answers. Before using a lie detector you have to calibrate it with test-questions, the person knows that false answers will cause juristic consequences

Comment: Wow, good answer -- very in depth. One slight point. You say `The inquisitions are part of ancient history. Ancient history is generally considered to end with the fall of the Western Roman empire in 476AD. The inquisitions are 12th century and high medieval. Doesn't effect your answer, but just thought you might like to know.

Comment: @jwenting, I know that it's tempting to look at the answer and thing TLDR.  :)  However, even the threat of torture is not a way to get _reliable_ information.  The effect is much the same that the person being interrogated will say whatever they think the person in power wants to hear.  And in most cases, lie to accomplish that.

Comment: true, but there are techniques to verify such information, especially if you have multiple people who may have it. Keep them separate so they can't synch stories for example. Not saying it's 100% reliable, but in interrogation nothing ever is. It's a tool that can be used however (and as stated elsewhere, so much is now considered torture that any interrogation could be considered as such as there's always some form of pressure (mental and/or physical) put on the subject).

Comment: @Larian, I just read _How to Break a Terrorist_ after you mentioned it above (thanks, it was awesome!). One point Alexander also makes is that when interrogators torture (or even just use what he calls 'old-school' control tactics) the necessary dehumanization that has to happen makes the interrogator himself ineffectual. When they lose respect for their enemies, they underestimate them and begin making simplifying assumptions. This, in turn makes the interrogation ineffective. (Sorry if this has already been said; this is a long post)

Comment: @Jeremy I don't think it HAS been mentioned.  Very pertinent information.

Comment: @muntoo Up until the point that it has the EDIT TO ADD should back up the answer sufficiently to provide a definitive NO.  However, since this is a contentious subject, I have taken the liberty of adding even more to truly drive the point home.  Since this is a bit of a subjective area of discussion, I felt it necessary to go on.

Comment: Anyone who has read this far in the comments will probably be fascinated by the report from the [Constitution Project's Task Force on Detainee Treatment](http://detaineetaskforce.org/). Astoundingly under-reported.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella, just came across this which is pretty damning and convincing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogation_of_Abu_Zubaydah#Ali_Soufan.27s_Congressional_testimony

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Given the number of comments and edits to this question, and the fact that DVK posted his series of critical comments *on the day the answer was first posted*, I'd say he was referring to an earlier version of the answer, especially since the sheer breadth of sources that have been added, in conjuncture with the wide range of sources supplied, debunk those comments.  If anything, his comments may have encouraged the sheer breadth that this answer has now.

Comment: This is in the news for now, but will probably disappear soon enough. Worth referencing here: http://www.intelligence.senate.gov/study2014/sscistudy1.pdf

Comment: @LarianLeQuella. Just seen this cited as a counter-example: http://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2004/12/tort-d13.html

Comment: Larian - I know this is old and widely cited - but there is a significant variation in the question's subject line and the essential summary of your answer. The difference is large enough that I suggest that the question's title, and not the answer, should ideally be changed. I realise that that may be undoable at this stage - and also that some or many may disagree that there is any need. I won't (even) say what the significant difference is. You will have long seen it if its real. If you, or anybody  else does not see it as 'obvious' & worth changing  then my opinion does not count :-).

Comment: @LarianLeQuella, I'm afraid there's too much cherry picking in this answer to justify an upvote. All of the sources come from **a country which has an interest in abolishing torture** and none of the studies are **controlled** [experiments](http://remember.org/educate/medexp). More importantly, your answer has many instances of "torture", but what kind of torture exactly? The kind of torture that US army of this era is willing to use against enemies is **at a completely different level** as [the kind of torture](http://goo.gl/5DpwZS) that Nazi, China, and other civilizations

Comment: [cont] are willing to use. The bottom line is simple: some torture methods are effective while others aren't. You may not get the truth from someone who knows the truth if you repeatedly punch him in the face, put him on an electric chair, or slice off his four limbs, but the same cannot be said if the Brazen bull or the Judas cradle is used. It totally depends on the torture method used. That is the **main factor**.

Comment: Great answer! I think it would deserve some kind of summary or "TL;DR:" along the lines "torture as an interrogation technique is good for extracting fake confessions for propaganda use, or having plausible explanation for physical punishment without trial [for revenge]", because that's pretty much full summary on the "advantages".

Answer (score 175):

Counter-argument: One of the most successful interrogators of Nazi Germany did not use torture. Quite the opposite really.

[Hanns Scharff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanns_Scharff#Technique), "Master Interrogator" of the Luftwaffe.

> Scharff was opposed to physically abusing prisoners to obtain information. Learning on the job, Scharff instead relied upon the Luftwaffe's approved list of techniques, **which mostly involved making the interrogator seem as if he is his prisoner's greatest advocate while in captivity.**
>
> Scharff described various experiences with new POWs, outlining the procedure most of his fellow interrogators were instructed to use. Initially, the POW's fear and sense of disorientation, combined with isolation while not in interrogation, were exploited to gain as much initial biographical information as possible. A prisoner was frequently warned that unless he could produce information beyond name, rank, and serial number, such as the name of his unit and airbase, the Luftwaffe would have no choice but to assume he was a spy and turn him over to the Gestapo for questioning. For Scharff, this technique apparently worked quite well. In addition to initially preying upon his prisoner's fears of the infamous Gestapo, he portrayed himself as their closest ally in their predicament, telling them that while he would like nothing more than to see them safely deposited in a POW camp, his hands were tied unless the prisoner gave him the few details that he requested to help him properly identify the prisoner as a true POW.
>
> After a prisoner's fear had been allayed, Scharff continued to act as a good friend, including sharing jokes, homemade food items, and occasionally alcoholic beverages. Scharff was fluent in English and knowledgeable about British customs and some American ones, which helped him to gain the trust and friendship of many of his prisoners. Some high profile prisoners were treated to outings to German airfields (one POW was even allowed to take a German aircraft for a trial run), tea with German fighter aces, swimming pool excursions, and luncheons, among other things. Prisoners were treated well medically at the nearby Hone Mark Hospital, and some POWs were occasionally allowed to visit their comrades at this hospital for company's sake, as well as the better meals provided there. Scharff was best known for taking his prisoners on strolls through the nearby woods, first having them swear an oath of honor that they would not attempt to escape during their walk. Scharff chose not to use these nature walks as a time to directly ask his prisoners obvious military-related questions, but instead relied on the POWs' desire to speak to anyone outside of isolated captivity about informal, generalized topics. **Prisoners often volunteered information the Luftwaffe had instructed Scharff to acquire, frequently without realizing they had done so.**

A good detail on the tale and methods used by Hanns Scharff is [The Interrogator: The Story of Hanns Joachim Scharff](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764302612), by Raymond Toliver.

The book [How To Break a Terrorist](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1416573151), by Matthew Alexander also describes how the US switched from harsher methods to more persuasive methods after their attempts to squeeze information through torture had failed.

Comment: Related story, in the other direction: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-20698098

Comment: Great example of how it's never too late to add another answer. Sounds like Scharff was the master of good cop, bad cop.

Comment: +1 for using a non-US and non-democratic-country source, though I suspect that the threat of torture counts somewhat as using torture.

Comment: Note that credible threat of torture (Gestapo) was effective.

Comment: @Muz, Good post, but "friend approach" is another topic altogether. Whether or not it works is orthogonal to the effectiveness of torture.

Comment: I thought it was a great example in that the Nazis would certainly be willing to torture, but chose not to do so because it was less effective.

Comment: @Bulwersator I see the stick (threat of torture / Gestapo) only used as a way to *initially* establish the "good cop" relationship. After that, the  information was obtained through carrots exclusively: strolls, meals, visits to comrades in the hospital, etc.

Comment: Very cool indeed, I've always wondered about different information techniques and this is just plain fascinating.

Answer (score 32):

> Is torture useful in interrogation? Is it feasible to torture accurate information out of people? Is it feasible to determine whether the information is likely accurate without outside confirmation?

If torture is used then it is sometimes useful. Information obtained from torture may or may not be accurate, and requires outside confirmation.

## Can interrogators determine whether information is accurate?

There are two problems:

1. The subject may not know the truth
2. The subject may not tell the truth

Within [INTELLIGENCE SCIENCE BOARD, EDUCING INFORMATION: INTERROGATION, SCI­ENCE AND ART National Defense Intelligence College Press (2006)](http://www.fas.org/irp/dni/educing.pdf):

- Chapter 3 discusses whether human interrogators can tell whether they are being deceived; and concludes, "not reliably".

> *We do not really know what we think we know.* Overall, knowledge of 
>   behavioral indicators that might assist in the detection of deception is very limited 
>   and provides little reliable information that could assist intelligence collectors 
>   operating anywhere outside the United States or Europe. Despite some progress 
>   in the ability to assess common criminals, results gleaned from the domestic 
>   population of criminals and college undergraduates may help us little in dealing 
>   with uncooperative detained soldiers or committed and possibly resistance-trained 
>   followers of radical movements.
>
> Very little is actually known about current populations of interest. In addition, 
>   this review failed to locate a single study examining the impact on deception 
>   detection of using interpreters/translators in questioning subjects. There is little 
>   reason to assume that data generalize across cultures, particularly Third World 
>   populations.

The "outside the United States or Europe" is a reference to earlier in the chapter where it talks about language barriers (the interrogator not being fluent in the subject's language) and cultural barriers (the interrogator not being fluent in the subject's culture, religion, etc.).

The chapter includes many statements such as,

> *People who adopt the belief that there are reliable cues to deception are 
>   frequently incorrect.* Significant research has studied people’s beliefs about 
>   indicators that someone is being deceptive and their own attitudes and confidence 
>   about their personal ability to be deceptive. A summary of 57 studies examining 
>   beliefs about nonverbal cues to deception indicated that many people do not 
>   actually know what they think they know: in other words, their beliefs are 
>   just as often wrong as they are right.36 These patterns of erroneous beliefs are 
>   widespread and are found equally among professional interrogators/investigators 
>   and novices.7

- Chapter 4 discusses whether there are mechanical aids to detect deception. It discusses many, including polygraphs, sodium pentothal, MRIs and PET scans, etc. It concludes,

> Thus, despite the polygraph’s shortcomings, there is currently no viable 
>   technical alternative to polygraphy. After reviewing the EEG and fMRI deception 
>   detection efforts, as well as some other psychophysiological candidate techniques 
>   (e.g., VSA), the National Research Council concluded that “some of the potential 
>   alternatives show promise, but none has yet been shown to outperform the 
>   polygraph

The polygraph isn't wholly reliable. Earlier in the chapter, it says,

> The accuracy of the polygraph is a matter of controversy. Some researchers 
>   believe that the current system with the CQT is no better than chance
>   (c.f. BenShakhar, 1991; Furedy, 1996; Saxe, 1991).
>   Other researchers estimate the accuracy 
>   at 75% to 80% (i.e., one error, on average, in four to ﬁ ve trials): Elaad and others 
>   (1992) with the GKT/CIT, MacLaren (2001) with the GKT/CIT, and Patrick and 
>   Iacono (1991) with the CQT. Supreme Court Justice John P. Stevens found “a host 
>   of studies that place the reliability of polygraph tests at 85 to 90 percent” (United 
>   States v. Scheffer, 523 U.S. 303, 333, quoted in Greeley, 2004, p. 129).

## Is there scientific evidence that torture works?

Chapter 10 of Ibid states that there hasn't [yet] been [published] scientific investigation:

> Eduction practices are methods, techniques, procedures, strategies, etc., 
>   employed as part of interviews and interrogations to draw out information 
>   from subjects, some of whom may initially be unwilling to provide information. Obviously educed information can provide an important source of 
>   HUMINT. Surprisingly, the last forty years have seen almost no scientific 
>   research examining eduction practices. Rather, our current knowledge is 
>   based on feedback and lessons learned from field experience. The “interrogation approaches” taught in standard interrogation training (e.g., Army 
>   Field Manual 34-52) have remained largely unchanged since World War 
>   II.
>
> This paper argues two points: first, that scientific investigation of eduction 
>   practices is needed to supplement lessons learned from field experience, 
>   and second, that various research venues are available to examine these 
>   practices. Research approaches could include both retrospective analyses 
>   of data about past interrogations (including those that used harsh methods) 
>   and new studies that relate different eduction practices to the value of information obtained.

It suggests that such research could be (but hasn't been) made, using as datum the records of past interrogations (including e.g. interrogations of American POWs).

## Is torture sometimes useful?

Anecdotal evidence suggests "yes":

- When the goal is short-term
- When the information can be verified externally

For example, [EVIDENCE GAINED FROM TORTURE:
WISHFUL THINKING, CHECKABILITY,
AND EXTREME CIRCUMSTANCES](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~jim/torturecardozo.pdf) cites the following story,

> Another case, not exactly of torture, but of truth confessed 
>   under extreme duress (hence logically very similar), is from opera­
>   tions against the Tamil Tigers. It involved a literal ticking bomb 
>   scenario: a security forces unit apprehended three terrorists who it 
>   suspected of planting a bomb somewhere in a city. They were 
>   brought before the officer in charge:
>
> > He asked them where the bomb was. The terrorists-highly 
> >     dedicated and steeled to resist interrogation-remained silent. 
> >     [He] asked the question again, advising them that if they did not 
> >     tell him what he wanted to know, he would kill them. They 
> >     were unmoved. So [he] took his pistol from his gun belt, 
> >     pointed it at the forehead of one of them, and shot him dead. 
> >     The other two, he said, talked immediately; the bomb, which 
> >     had been placed in a crowded railway station and set to explode 
> >     during the evening rush hour, was found and defused, and 
> >     countless lives were saved.16

It mentions a case where torture has been effective in American civilian police-work,

> Torture is not restricted to operations against terrorists; it is 
>   also resorted to in more mundane police work. In Leon v. Wain­
>   wright, the Eleventh Circuit considered a case where the police ap­
>   prehended one of two kidnappers of a taxi driver while the 
>   kidnapper was collecting ransom. The court found that when [the 
>   kidnapper] refused to tell them [the police] the location, he was set 
>   upon by several of the officers. .. [T]hey threatened and physi­
>   cally abused him by twisting his arm and choking him until he re­
>   vealed where [the taxi driver] was being held.21 The court held 
>   these actions to be reasonable given the "immediate necessity" to 
>   save the driver's life. The important point is that the information 
>   confessed turned out to be true.22

It also mentions a case where information obtained was unreliable or misleading,

> It is possible to find, on the other hand, cases in which infor­mation gained under torture by experienced interrogators turned 
>   out to be false. A case that proved significant for the intelligence 
>   failures in the lead-up to the Iraq War is that of Ibn al-Shaykh al­
>   Libi, a Libyan al-Qaeda operative captured while fleeing Afghani­stan around the end of 2001. Al-Libi later claimed that, under tor­ture, he fabricated evidence that Iraq had provided chemical and 
>   biological warfare training to al-Qaeda. This evidence appears to 
>   have been a main source of false claims by President Bush that 
>   there were links between Iraq and al-Qaeda. Based on the incom­plete evidence available, it appears that al-Libi did fabricate such 
>   evidence under torture or the threat of torture. However, it is un­clear whether he did so to avoid torture, as in the classic scenario 
>   of a tortured interrogee telling the interrogator anything he wants 
>   to hear, or whether he did so deliberately to encourage the United 
>   States to invade Iraq and thus radicalize the Arab world.23 Despite 
>   the fragmentary nature of these cases, they suggest, when taken as 
>   a whole, that the reliability of evidence gained from torture should 
>   not be dismissed on the basis that an interrogee will confess to 
>   anything.